# ошибка: status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

Не получается никак запустить mongodb 3.6 на сервере.
Для запуска ввожу команду:

```
root@91508:/# sudo systemctl start mongodb
```

Для проверки статуса так:

```
root@91508:/# sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

В ответ выдает ошибку:

```
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-02-05 10:19:33 +07; 22 min ago
 Main PID: 5321 (code=exited, status=2)

Feb 05 10:19:33 91508.local systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Feb 05 10:19:33 91508.local systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Feb 05 10:19:33 91508.local systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 05 10:19:33 91508.local systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Код 2 означает что-то такое

> The specified options are in error or are incompatible with other
>   options.

Содержимое /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Содержимое /etc/mongod.conf:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

auth=true

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Создал нужные директории и установил права:

```
mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb/
mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb/
mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb/
mkdir -p /data/db/

chown mongodb:mongodb /var/run/mongodb/
chown mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb/
chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/
chown mongodb:mongodb /data/db

chmod 0755 /var/log/mongodb/
chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb/
chmod 0755 /var/lib/mongodb/
chmod 0755 /data/db/
```

Ничего не помогает, так и не получилось. Пробовал переустанавливать, такая же ситуация. Failed пишет всегда.

Еще иногда такая ошибка выпадает непонятно когда:

```
91508.local mongod[7317]: Error parsing YAML config file: yaml-cpp: error at line 26, column 1: end of map not f
91508.local mongod[7317]: try 'usr/bin/mongod --help' for more information
```

Comment: 26-я строка — `auth=true`. это явно не соответствует синтаксису языка yaml. вероятно, подразумевалось что-то вроде `auth: true`

Comment: Благодарю, в это и была ошибка. Все перерыл, но было все так просто.